# Extract portion of string after or before given number of periods

Tags: r, string

I'm hoping to extract a portion of a string in R.  I have the following character vector:

```
vars <- c("PANAS.pos.1","PANAS.neg.1",
"PANAS.pos.2","PANAS.neg.2",
"PANAS.pos.3","PANAS.neg.3",
"PANAS.pos.4","PANAS.neg.4",
"IPANAT.pos.1","IPANAT.neg.1",
"IPANAT.pos.2","IPANAT.neg.2",
"IPANAT.pos.3","IPANAT.neg.3",
"IPANAT.pos.4","IPANAT.neg.4")
```

And I'm wanting to break it into two character vector, one with the text alone and one with the number alone, like this:

```
v1 <- c(PANAS.pos, PANAS.neg, PANAS.pos, PANAS.neg, etc...)
v2 <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, etc...)
```

I tried using sub( ) but am having trouble with the period, I think.  I've also considered substr( ) but the text portions are not the same length.

Comment: How about `v1 <- substring(vars, 1, nchar(vars)-2); v2 <- as.numeric(substring(vars, nchar(vars)))`

Comment: or use a regex `v1 <- unlist(strsplit(vars, split = '\\.\\d'))`

Comment: Will the numbers at the end ever be more than 9?

Comment: Not in this example, but I'd still like to learn the general form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
v1 <- sub("\\.[0-9]+$", "", vars)
v2 <-  as.numeric(sub(".*\\.", "",vars))
```

In the first case `v1`, we are matching the `dot(.)` followed by numbers `[0-9]+` at the end of (`$`) string and replace it with `""` in the second part of `sub` argument.  For `v2`, `".*` it matches one or more than one elements upto the last dot (`\\.`) and replace it with `""`.

Or as suggested by @Richard Scriven for `v1`. Here, it is a bit more general (I guess).  It matches `(.*)` one or more element and capture that as a group `( )` followed by a dot `[.]` (the last dot) followed by one or more elements (up to the end of string though it is not specified with `$`).  For the second part of the argument ,we use `\\1` to get the captured group.  In this case, there is only one group.

```
sub("(.*)[.].*", "\\1", vars)
```

Or you could use `strplit` with `regex` `lookahead`.  Here, we are asking to split by dot (`\\.`) that is followed by a digit `(?=\\d)`. The output will be a list.

```
 strsplit(vars, "\\.(?=\\d)", perl=TRUE) #Inspired from @rawr's comment
```

Comment: The first one could be `sub("(.*)[.].*", "\\1", vars)`

Comment: Thanks!  It worked.  Any tips on decoding the regular expression portion here?  I can't seem to determine the pattern of ., *, /, etc.

Answer (score 5):

The **qdap** package has the convienence functions `beg2char` & `char2end` that handle this:

```
library(qdap)
v1 <- beg2char(vars, ".", 2)
v2 <- as.numeric(char2end(vars, ".", 2))

## > beg2char(vars, ".", 2)
##  [1] "PANAS.pos"  "PANAS.neg"  "PANAS.pos"  "PANAS.neg"  "PANAS.pos" 
##  [6] "PANAS.neg"  "PANAS.pos"  "PANAS.neg"  "IPANAT.pos" "IPANAT.neg"
## [11] "IPANAT.pos" "IPANAT.neg" "IPANAT.pos" "IPANAT.neg" "IPANAT.pos"
## [16] "IPANAT.neg"

## > as.numeric(char2end(vars, ".", 2))
##  [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4
```